# This app is blocked message when using gActions CLI

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

I downloaded gActions CLI on windows x64 bit machine. after issuing the login command and pasting the the browser link i get the below error:
This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

Comment: Where did you download gactions? What version is it?

Comment: Getting this same error! Must be new. I'm on v3.2.0, downloaded from [this page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart?authuser=0#install_the_gactions_command-line_tool)

Comment: I downloaded it from here:https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart#install_the_gactions_command-line_tool

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Was having the same issue when I downloaded the gactions script manually from [this page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart#install_the_gactions_command-line_tool).

I was able to resolve the issue when I instead downloaded the utility from npm:

```sh
npm i -g @assistant/gactions
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm!

Comment: That's really bizarre that it has issues when downloading from the main page, but not when adding through node or yarn... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
gactions login --actions-builder-only
```

I installed on an M1 Mac using `brew install gactions`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Mac/Linux system, not verified on Windows. 
You have to provide proper permissions while running the command.

Example : -  `sudo gactions login`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me too, but only after I deleted the gactions.exe file I had earlier downloaded (and had set a path environment variable for).