# Can't authenticate gactions CLI to work with Google Assistant, Actions On Google

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

Google Assistant Docs, Quick Start, advises to run gactions login to authenticate CLI https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart

When I run 'gactions login', I get this message:

Gactions needs access to your Google account. Please copy & paste the URL below into a web browser and follow the instructions there. Then copy and paste the authorization code from the browser back here. Visit this URL:...

When I visit URL, I get this message: This app is blocked. This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

On another post, it was suggested I run npm i -g @assistant/gactions and then try again.  But that didn't work.

Comment: For anyone finding this, I was able to use `npm i -g @assistant/gactions` on MacOS, as per the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70328713. I first ensured I deleted the previous executable that was in /usr/local/bin/gactions. Not sure why it didn't work for you.